# Intesllisense methods for expect incorrect

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jestjs

When using intellisense in VS-Code, it gives autocomplete suggestions for an older version of expect than what I'm using,. The API has changed since it was donated to the Jest project, but for some reason, it still shows the old methods, but none of the replacement methods, like `toHaveProperty`.

Took a lot of effort to find out why my tests weren't working, but haven't been able to find an answer as to what could be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code sources its type definitions for JavaScript from the `@types` namespace on NPM, which contains definition files that are automatically pulled from the [DefinitelyTyped GitHub repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/).

In your case, the type definitions will be coming from the [`@types/expect` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/expect), which specifies in the README that it exposes the files from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/expect.

If you look at the timestamps on said files, you'll notice they haven't been updated in 5 months! That is most likely the source of your issue.

You (or someone else) will need to submit an updated type definition to make automatic type acquisition function properly for that library. Alternatively, [you can override the type definitions locally or disable the feature altogether](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_7#_better-javascript-intellisense).